# Mysql select - all from left and only matching right table

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have two tables:

1. `employees`

   [id, first_name, last_name, status]
2. `absence`

   [id, employee_id, reason_type, date_from, date_to

I can do something like:

```
SELECT e.first_name, e.last_name, e.status, a.reason_type FROM employees e JOIN absence a ON e.id=a.employee_id
WHERE curdate() between date_from and date_to
```

but it will give me only those employees that are found in `absence` table.

Is there a way to get a list of ALL employees and their status (for those found in `absence` table matching condition `currdate() between date_from and date_to` return 'Yes' and `reason_type`) and for others say No and null for `reason_type`.

Thanks.

Comment: Do a `LEFT JOIN`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for a `left join`, but you have to be careful about the `where` clause:

```
SELECT e.first_name, e.last_name, e.status, a.reason_type
FROM employees e LEFT JOIN
     absence a
     ON e.id = a.employee_id AND
        curdate() between a.date_from and a.date_to ;
```

Answer (score 2):

You want a `LEFT JOIN`. That does exactly what you want: all values on the left-hand side of the join, and `null` on the right if there's no match.

There's also (unsurprisingly) a `RIGHT JOIN`, that does things the other way round.

[image]

Comment: Take into account though that FULL OUTER JOIN does not exist in Mysql

Answer (score -1):

You can use the below query..

```
SELECT e.first_name, e.last_name, e.status, a.reason_type 
FROM employees e 
 LEFT JOIN absence a ON e.id=a.employee_id
WHERE curdate() between date_from and date_to
```